# How to use awk to split the row(record)?

Tags: awk

File:

```
data
A B
C D
data
E F
G H
data
I J
K L
M N
```

Wanted result:

```
I J
K L
M N
```

How to split by "data"?
I have been search from google about how to use awk, But most of relative awk is split the column.

Comment: so you just need to rip off `data` right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `data` as the record separator and print the last record:

```
$ awk -v RS=data 'END{print}' File

I J
K L
M N
```

This requires an awk, such as GNU awk (gawk) or mawk, that supports multi-character values for `RS`.

Comment: COOL!! this is what i want

Comment: Thanks, @Kusalananda, I added the note about awk versions to the answer.  I left in the blanks lines, in part, for code simplicity and, in part, because the questions shows blank lines in the same places.  (Separately, I see that you have added several good alternative solutions: +1)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/^data/ { lines = ""; next } { lines = (lines == "" ? $0 : lines ORS $0) } END { print lines }' file
I J
K L
M N
```

This uses `awk` to get the contents of the input after the last line that starts with the string `data`.  This is done by saving each section of lines after such a line into the `lines` variable.   Each time a line that starts with `data` is encountered, this variable is emptied.   The variable's value is printed when reaching the end of input.

---

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed -n 'H;${ x; s/.*\ndata\n//p; }' file
I J
K L
M N
```

We add all lines into the hold space.  When encountering the last line, the hold space is swapped into the pattern space and everything up to a the string `data` (flanked a newline on either side) is removed before the remaining bits are printed.

---

Using `ed`:

```
$ printf "?^data?ka\n1,'ad\n,p\nQ\n" | ed -s file
I J
K L
M N
```

or,

```
ed -s file <<END_ED
?^data?ka
1,'ad
,p
Q
END_ED
```

Here, we first search backwards for the last occurrence of the string `data` at the start of a line and label that line (the we call the label `a`). Then we delete from the start of the buffer to the labelled line.  The `,p` simply outputs the full contents of the buffer.

With non-GNU `ed`, the final `Q` (to quit without saving) is probably not needed.

Answer (score 0):

To split records on "data" instead of a newline, set the RS (record separator) variable.

You're only interested in the 4th record (the first record is before the first "data"; it's empty) so print only when NR is 4.

`cat file | awk 'BEGIN {RS="data\n"}; NR==4 {print}'`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the data what I want doesn't always at 4th record, I want the last one, sorry I didn't describe it vert well.

Answer (score 0):

Done by below method and it worked fine
Command:

```
tac file.txt|sed -n '1,/data/p'| tac| sed -n '2,$p'
```

output

```
 I J
 K L
 M N
```